# Convert 32 bit driver to 64 bit

Tags: 64-bit, driver, 32bit-64bit, 32-bit

I have an old USB MPEG-I Encoder. I can use "URANUSLT.SYS" in Driver Disk to install the driver on my PC which runs win7 32-Bits but on my laptop which runs win7 64-Bit it says driver not found.
Waiting for your help
Thanks

Comment: You can't magically "convert" a 32-bit driver into a 64-bit driver. The vendor of the driver has to port it (change to be 64-bit compatible and recompile to produce a new driver). Contact the company who provides the driver. (In addition, this isn't a programming question; it's better suited for [su] instead. Please take the offered tour before posting at any of the [se] sites, and check the guidelines in the [help] to make sure you've chosen the proper site. Thanks.)

Comment: unfotunatly,the company doesn't exist any more.